# How to use tikzstyle locally?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

You can use `\tikzstyle{mystyle}=[some options];` to define a custom `mystyle` globally, that means it affects all tikz graphics in the document, but is there also something similar if you want to define a custom `mystyle` just within one `tikzpicture`?

Comment: You should use `\tikzset` (`mystyle/.style={}`) nowadays. That will also work locally.

Comment: @TeXnician I didn't know about `tikzset`, is this the preferred way now?

Comment: I don't think the linked question is really a duplicate (and maybe this questions get answered somewhere in that lengthy post). The truth is: `\tikzstyle`, `\tikzset` and `[…]` all work locally, just use them in a group/environment/scope and not in the preamble.

Comment: And I also don't think that the answers here really help. `\tikzset` or `\tikzstyle` doesn't matter. In both answers `mystyle` is still defined globally (and overwritten locally). But just because it is defined, doesn't mean it has an effect on the pictures until it used there somewhere. (Some styles have obviously, like `every picture`, `every node`, `every edge`, …)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\tikzset` instead of the `\tikzstyle` approach. This will allow local key-value settings.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{mystyle/.style={fill=blue}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[mystyle] {Test};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begingroup
    \tikzset{mystyle/.style={fill=yellow}}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[mystyle] {Test};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \endgroup
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[mystyle] {Test};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Instead of groups and `\tikzset`, add the style definition to the optional argument of the `tikzpicture` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{mystyle/.style={fill=blue}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[mystyle] {Test};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[mystyle/.style={fill=yellow}]
        \node[mystyle] {Test};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[mystyle] {Test};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```